# Toon Style Explosion

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, effects, npr

I want to make toon style Explosion similar to that which is given below:

[image: Toon Explosion]
A simple setup for **material** would be helpful. References:

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: Are you requesting a tutorial or do you have some specific problem to solve?

Comment: Hi. This site works best for specific problems. Best to give it a go and come back here when you come up against problem (even if that's the first step).

Comment: @RayMairlot I just want material setup for that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'll do a smoke simulation which I can do. But problem is in material Setup...

Comment: The blender-(internal)render information should be added as a tag, @Shehroz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somethink like this ? (Using similar, not same teqniques?)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XZjhESZPxA
[image]

At the firs place, its not my tutorial, originally its from Pierrick Picaut
and his P2Design. Also you can download whole tutorial from official https://gumroad.com/l/Stylised-explosion-blender for free.

And how he made it ?

The explosion is created by animated mesh with various noise displacement and animated parameters. You can use particle system with noisy-spheres like the mesh also.

For material Pierrick used MatCaps, with right outline setting for smoke, but you can use whatever you like if you get right fresnel-like faced soft outline.
[image]

For the exact explosion he used Color ramp and emmission node like this:
[image]
This system of material can be used for every toon-like visual, you can use every color you want, or mix with other properties like noises or lights.

So after all if you want change the smoke from shiny yellow-red color to calssic grey smoke Pierrick used Mix node and he animated fac property with greater then mathematical node.

[image]

From there is the same steps for every part of explosion. But you can use transparency node instead color ramp at the second input in mix node, so you will get only kinf of outlines for the details.

Comment: Nice edit. This is how a "link only answer" should be made. Well done with the attribution too.

Comment: where is the icon "thank you and like it"  ? :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that its man made drawing, that seams to be coloured based upon "camera facing angle of surface area" of the smoke pattern. In cycles there is no such area as smoke isn't a surface-mesh object but rather based upon voxel density.

There are some complex ways to turn particles into mesh data (as particles can be source for smoke), but it would be quite extreme to do so.

Maybe the fastest way to do it is mimic it, with Greace Pencil tools (draw it and modify it). Even that though is not really easy, and it requires some skill. Note that greace pencil is used a lot by traditional 2d animators, so if your one I highly recommend you to dive into that area of Blender.

Maybe not the answer you hoped for, but just telling before you spend days on it.

Comment: But I should Mention The Game Fortnite they have very similar explosion to this one. It is not of that game though. Try searching Fortnite Explosion you'll see many similar explosions...

Comment: Games often use sprites for that, or they have shaders that are not available in Blender.

Comment: 2D games use Sprites but in 3D the case is different. Fortnite is 3D game...

Comment: Even in 3D games 2D sprites are used a lot, ea series of random transparant sprite to emulate smoke of a building in fire. For openGL Shader languages they're simple transparant texture objects facing the camera always.
Games usually tend to use the fastest solutions to render, so if it can be tricked fast then thats how its done, i kinda doubt they would use voxel to mesh conversions cause those cost time.

Comment: These planes are called Billboard. If they look well in 3D so How can I use in my Animated Scene such that I could create a illusion of 3D...

Comment: Animated Gifs of the explosion, with a modifier to point a textured surface towards the camera. Maybe with some slight scripting not sure how well animated gifs are supported in Blender(used to be troublesome a few years ago, might be fixed now).

Comment: one could also switch textures by animating a value over math nodes smaller than (without scripting).

Comment: I think it can be done by setting up a video texture in texture pannel. I'll check out. Anyway Thanks! For Help......

Comment: I got your idea but you should check out this video  https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DyCL_TiembYI&ved=0ahUKEwi52Onv4oXcAhXpK8AKHXZXBGkQo7QBCCQwAA&usg=AOvVaw0PhWDn2QadGKdntSADmyec it looks a lot more complex than a gif facing camera...

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dcr-Lh1cLA20&ved=0ahUKEwj0k5eN5IXcAhVJTcAKHdRaCMMQo7QBCCwwBQ&usg=AOvVaw0cZWDadGN8SyznlAVUW-go its 3D I'm sure if Houdini can do that so why not blender...